# SQL Server: how to get random sample from a time period based on parameters in an existing query?

Tags: t-sql, random

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select 
id,
city,
gender,
age,
ethnicity
from customer
where visit_date between '20220201' and '20220228'
```

So I want to create a random sample that will have similar or close characteristics from the query above but from a different time frame. For the sake of this example, let's say I want to find similar sample from the year before so the `visit_date between '20210201' and '20210228'`.

For example, there query above produced 134 rows, I will expect the random sample to also have 134 rows and similar characteristics (different id but same match on city, gender, age, and ethnicy) from the query above but from the year before.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. What about all of the edge cases, e.g. there aren't enough organisms with matching (or "similar") ethnicities to return 134 rows? Return a different number of rows? Return less "similar" ethnicities? Try a different city that still rhymes with "Orange"?

Comment: @HABO: good point, if there's no exact match then it would be the nearest match. And I'm not sure what you're getting at with the formatting, if you have suggestions please suggest an edit rather than sending a link.

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate a mix of values from existing data is to select a sampling of data from the existing table and shuffle the data using random numbers assigned to each column.

More specifically, the following will:

1. Extract a pseudo-random selection of data from the source table
2. Assign pseudo-random numbers to each column of interest
3. Sort each column by its associated random number
4. Assign sequence numbers reflecting the new order
5. Use those sequence numbers to zip up the data into new rows

The following demonstrates this for data selected from the Person table in the AdventureWorks sample database.

```
DECLARE @SampleSize INT = 10
DECLARE @ResultSize INT = 5
DECLARE @Seed VARCHAR(10) = '' -- Change this for different results

;WITH SAMPLE AS (
    SELECT TOP (@SampleSize)
        BusinessEntityID,
        FirstName, MiddleName, LastName,
        R1 = HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'A' + Seed),
        R2 = HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'B' + Seed),
        R3 = HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'C' + Seed)
    FROM Person.Person P -- From AdventureWorks sample database
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT Seed = @Seed + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), BusinessEntityID)) X
    ORDER BY HASHBYTES('SHA1', Seed)
)
SELECT TOP (@ResultSize)
    C1.Seq, C1.FirstName, C2.MiddleName, C3.LastName
FROM (
    SELECT Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R1), FirstName
    FROM SAMPLE
) C1
JOIN (
    SELECT Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R2), MiddleName
    FROM SAMPLE
) C2 ON C2.Seq = C1.Seq
JOIN (
    SELECT Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY R3), LastName
    FROM SAMPLE
) C3 ON C3.Seq = C1.Seq
ORDER BY C1.Seq
```

Results (selected sample data plus randomizers):

| BusinessEntityID | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | R1 | R2 | R3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16055 | Andre | E | Arun | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 19284 | Erik | S | Gutierrez | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 9079 | Erin |  | Rogers | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 11824 | Victoria | V | Garcia | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 15701 | Jack | W | Edwards | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 6117 | Beth |  | Rubio | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 16041 | Jackson |  | Turner | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 12649 | Sarah |  | Griffin | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 15795 | Isaac |  | Collins | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |
| 8153 | Jacqueline |  | Torres | (randomizer) | (randomizer) | (randomizer) |

Results (after shuffle):

| Seq | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Victoria | W | Torres |
| 2 | Andre |  | Collins |
| 3 | Erik | V | Rogers |
| 4 | Jack |  | Gutierrez |
| 5 | Erin | E | Rubio |

The HASHBYTES function is used to generate a repeatable, but sufficiently randomized pattern for selecting and shuffling the data. (The SQL Server RAND() function just wasn't up to the task.) Changing @Seed will change the results. Setting @Seed to something like GETDATE() will yield different results with each run.

You of course will need to replace the source table and column references to suit your needs. You can also add additional selection criteria, such as your desired date range. What you choose in place of BusinessEntityID to initially randomize the data is not critical, but a mostly unique value like a PK would work best.

See [this db<>fiddle[(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=f12774f0f00241e08cdf5cb1b7fb959b) for a demo.